# Why is is Chrome's scroll behavior different and problematic?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, logitech-mouse

While I had never used Chrome as main browser, I do have to use it some for webdev and some functions, unfortunately unique to it.

Over the years it has been continuously plagued with scroll issues. Scrolling to fast, or too slow, or too jerky. Basically something making it scroll differently from any other applications which all somehow manage to just scroll without issue.

Usually I somehow manage to get it to passable state... Until they proudly announce scroll was "improved" again and all hell breaks loose.

Lately I got in a habit of quickly checking scroll after clicking into Chrome window and quickly switching out/in if behavior is *off*. Surprisingly effective, but still highly annoying.

That said:

- why and how does Chrome screw up scroll, as opposed to every other app?
- what are relevant settings/flags for its scrolling behavior and what exactly do they do?
- is there any hope to have Chrome just respect system scroll settings/manner and act consistently?

Configuration:

- Win7x64
- Chrome stable, autoupdate
- Logitech Performance MX mouse (set to normal "clicky" scroll, not friction-less one)